# rabbitmq cluster all down ,when first slave node,queue is state down

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, high-availability

I have 3 nodes this disc mode and "ha-mode is all". rabbitmq version 3.6.4

when I try to stop all nodes, first I stop two slave nodes,end stop master nodes. Assume that master node is broken and can't be started. I use `rabbitmqctl force_boot` setup one slave node, I found queue state is down.

I don't think this is right. I think the slave node setup become master, and queue is available. Do not consider whether the message is lost.

But, first stop master node,  then stop new master node, end last node. I can
`rabbitmqctl force_boot` setup any node. any node is available.

Comment: Is it reproducible ? I mean did you have this problem on time? is it a test ? can you also post the logs ? I suggest to move this question on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're ending up with unsynchronized slaves and by default RabbitMQ will refuse to fail over to an unsynchronised slave on controlled master shutdown.

> **Stopping master nodes with only unsynchronised slaves**
>
> It's possible that when you shut down a master node that all available slaves are unsynchronised. A common situation in which this can occur is rolling cluster upgrades. By default, RabbitMQ will refuse to fail over to an unsynchronised slave on controlled master shutdown (i.e. explicit stop of the RabbitMQ service or shutdown of the OS) in order to avoid message loss; instead the entire queue will shut down as if the unsynchronised slaves were not there. An uncontrolled master shutdown (i.e. server or node crash, or network outage) will still trigger a failover even to an unsynchronised slave.
>
> If you would prefer to have master nodes fail over to unsynchronised slaves in all circumstances (i.e. you would choose availability of the queue over avoiding message loss) then you can set the ha-promote-on-shutdown policy key to always rather than its default value of when-synced.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html